# getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager

Tags: java, apache-poi, log4j, slf4j, uberjar

I am getting this error after I update apache poi jar from 4.0.1 to 4.1.2 and aem-uber-jar 6.5.11 jar to 6.5.17

```
from this line  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inStream))

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<clinit>(XSSFWorkbook.java:195)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<clinit>(XSSFWorkbook.java:195)
```

I  tried reverting version it is working fine on lower version

Comment: Try removing aem-uber-jar and use Maven Shade instead